# Option menu widget in tkinter wont show beyond option number 1167

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a long list of options for an option menu widget, but the menu always ends at option number 1167.

Here is the code:

---

```
from tkinter import *
  
root = Tk()
root.geometry( "200x200" )
  
options = [str(i) for i in range(2000)]
  
selected = StringVar()

selected.set( "1" )
  
drop = OptionMenu( root , selected , options )

drop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Theoretically, the option menu should go up to 2000, but it stops at 1167.

Here is an image: [end of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rLAS.png)

Is there some way to fix this? should I use a different widget?

Thanks - Ian

Comment: I suspect that the limit you're actually hitting is the maximum coordinate value of 32767 (Tkinter internally uses 16-bit integers for coordinates).  The point at which your menu broke is consistent with the menu items being 28 pixels tall.  There's no fix, but a 2000-item menu seems horribly unusable anyway.  If the items are actually numbers, then a Spinbox widget seems much more appropriate.

Comment: @jasonharper a limit like that doesn't seem obvious; I'd say it's worth verifying and writing up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else gets themselves into this situation, I recommend the alternative I used: using a listbox instead. The code I wrote below isnt great, but it shows the basic idea.

For more info on the Listbox widget, visit: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-listbox-widget/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-selected-value-from-listbox-in-tkinter/

---

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x250")

#ol stands for Option List

def manage_ol(mode,items):
  global selected,ol_frame,ol

  if mode == 1:
    ol_frame = Frame(root)
    ol_frame.pack()
    ol = Listbox(ol_frame)
    for i in range(len(items)):
      ol.insert(i,items[i])
      ol.pack()
    ol_select = Button(ol_frame,text = 'select',command     = lambda: manage_ol(2,None))
    ol_select.pack()

  else:
    selected = ol.curselection()[0]
    print(ol.get(selected))
    ol_frame.destroy()

items = ['a','b','c','d','e']

ol_start = Button(root,text = 'option list',command = lambda: manage_ol(1,items))
ol_start.pack()

root.mainloop()
```